# R Append character to percentage of rows with matching values

Tags: r, append

I have a dataframe 'df' that looks like this:

| Date | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 13:00:00 | AMRO | 3 |
| 2022-03-14 13:10:00 | AMRO | 4 |
| 2022-03-14 13:20:00 | CHSP | 5 |
| 2022-03-14 13:30:00 | CHSP | 6 |
| 2022-03-14 13:40:00 | AMRO | 7 |
| 2022-03-14 13:50:00 | CHSP | 8 |
| 2022-03-14 14:00:00 | AMRO | 40 |
| 2022-03-14 14:10:00 | AMRO | 50 |
| 2022-03-14 14:20:00 | CHSP | 60 |
| 2022-03-14 14:30:00 | AMRO | 70 |
| 2022-03-14 14:40:00 | AMRO | 80 |
| 2022-03-14 14:50:00 | CHSP | 90 |

How do I randomly append " 1" to fifty percent of AMRO values in column 'Value1' and thirty percent of CHSP values in column 'Value1'? The ideal solution would be to use a list of percentages with matching four letter codes to modify the different four letter codes in Value1 in case there are many different four letter codes and not just AMRO and CHSP as seen here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach using dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
probs <- data.frame(Value1 = c("AMRO", "CHSP"), prob = c(0.5, 0.3))
set.seed(42)
out <- quux %>%
  left_join(probs, by = "Value1") %>%
  group_by(Value1) %>%
  mutate(Value1b = paste0(Value1, if_else(row_number() %in% sample(n(), size=ceiling(n()*first(prob))), "1", ""))) %>%
  ungroup()
out
# # A tibble: 12 × 5
#    Date                Value1 Value2  prob Value1b
#    <chr>               <chr>   <int> <dbl> <chr>  
#  1 2022-03-14 13:00:00 AMRO        3   0.5 AMRO1  
#  2 2022-03-14 13:10:00 AMRO        4   0.5 AMRO   
#  3 2022-03-14 13:20:00 CHSP        5   0.3 CHSP   
#  4 2022-03-14 13:30:00 CHSP        6   0.3 CHSP1  
#  5 2022-03-14 13:40:00 AMRO        7   0.5 AMRO   
#  6 2022-03-14 13:50:00 CHSP        8   0.3 CHSP   
#  7 2022-03-14 14:00:00 AMRO       40   0.5 AMRO   
#  8 2022-03-14 14:10:00 AMRO       50   0.5 AMRO1  
#  9 2022-03-14 14:20:00 CHSP       60   0.3 CHSP1  
# 10 2022-03-14 14:30:00 AMRO       70   0.5 AMRO1  
# 11 2022-03-14 14:40:00 AMRO       80   0.5 AMRO1  
# 12 2022-03-14 14:50:00 CHSP       90   0.3 CHSP
```

We can see the change in proportions with a couple calls to `table`:

```r
table(out$Value1)
# AMRO CHSP 
#    7    5 
table(out$Value1b)
#  AMRO AMRO1  CHSP CHSP1 
#     3     4     3     2
```

I assigned to a new name `Value1b` just for side-by-side comparison; feel free to assign it right back onto `Value1` if you aren't worried about "losing" that original information :-)

I chose to use `row_number() %in% sample(..)` because the use of `runif` could have resulted in many fewer or more than the `probs$prob`.

I chose the use of a "dictionary" of sorts to `left_join` in to the data so that if you have more `Value1` values than just two it would be easy enough to extend to them. (One could also use `dplyr::case_when` instead of the joined data.)

Comment: First answer in, so I'm giving you the answer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```r
val.perc <- c(AMRO = 50, CHSP = 30)
set.seed(1)
for (gr in names(val.perc)) {
  i <- which(df$Value1 == gr)
  df$Value1[i[sample(length(i), round(length(i) * val.perc[gr] / 100))]] <- 
    paste(gr, 1)
}

table(df$Value1)
#  AMRO AMRO 1   CHSP CHSP 1 
#     3      4      3      2
```

Comment: A wonderful solution, and quite simple.  Thank you for your time!